# How to load page load javascript when update progress is over

Tags: web-part, javascript, jquery

How to load **page load javascript** when update progress is over.

$(function() 
{

// how to load this after update progress is over

}

**Explanation**

My Grid inside update panel..

In Grid some of textbox controls.

I fired javascript on that textboxes when page load.

My javascript run perfect when page load.

when i button click(with AsyncPostBackTrigger) again grid refreshed without page postback(because of update panel).

so my javascript not fired when grid refreshed again.

How to run javascript again....

Comment: There are many meanings for "update progress", please explain. Also, what have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

You can to use [ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff411788%28v=office.14%29.aspx) and the script will execute after the process.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function(){ ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(ViewItem, "sp.js"); };
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways you could do this.

One way is register a start-up script in the behind code using the `ScriptManager`

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page,Page.GetType(),"MyScript","MyCodeHook()",true);
```

This will call the provided code when the page does the async postback.

Another method is to use the `PageRequestManager` [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311028%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Put your page load code into one or more functions and then call those functions when your update progress is over.

Comment: How to call that function when update progress is over

Comment: @Chandegara - what is "update progress"?  That is not a standard term in browsers.  You need to explain what "update progress" is so we can advise on how to hook your code to the completion of that.  Is it a SharePoint event?